# Angular 6 - Start animation when first one finishes

Tags: angular, animation, transition

Using Angular 6, I have 4 transitions/steps that I would like to occur:

1. Using ngIf a div 1 will display (containing buttons), slide up
2. The submit button will change color from left to right, it's a timer where user has 10 seconds to click until it auto clicks, sets bool 'submitted' to true
3. Div 1 will slide down off screen
4. Div 2 will slide up (also using ngIf)

I have code to do my transitions, but I would like to make them wait before executing the next

Is using stagger the only reasonable way to accomplish this? ie - https://angular.io/api/animations/stagger

Here's what I have so far to change my button color from left to right in 10s and another to slide the div up and down

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  animations: [
    trigger('changeButtonColor', [
      state('initial', style({
        'background-position': 'right bottom'
      })),
      transition('initial=>final', animate('10000ms'))
    ]),
    trigger('showSubmitButtons', [
      transition(':enter', [
        style({transform: 'translateY(100%)'}),
        animate(1500, style({transform: 'translateY(0%)'}))
      ]),
      transition(':leave', [
        animate(1500, style({transform: 'translateY(100%)'}))
      ])
    ]),
  ]
})
```

And here's a quick html snip:

```
    <div class="actionButtons" *ngIf="!submitted" [@showSubmitButtons]>
            <button [@changeButtonColor]=currentState (@changeButtonColor.done)="submitImage()" id="submitBtn" class="submitButton" (click)="submitImage()"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></button>
            <button id="restartBtn" class="myButton" (click)="resetCapture()"><i class="fas fa-redo-alt"></i></button>
    </div>

    <div class="offlineContent" *ngIf="submitted" [@showSubmitButtons]>
        <h1>Thank You!</h1>
        <button id="restartBtn" class="myButton" (click)="resetCapture()"><i class="fas fa-redo-alt"></i></button>
    </div>
```

**Edit - I put together a stackblitz, it's not perfect but at the least can see how I need a wait specifically after clicking the Submit button, would like to wait for the buttons to slide down fully until the new div slides up.

My blitz isn't showing it (difficulty moving code from my project over to small sample), but would also like my Submit button color transition to wait until the div has slide up

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8xufpf

Comment: Can you accomplish it by setting an animation delay? `animate('1.5s 10s', style({transform: 'translateY(0%)'}))` https://angular.io/api/animations/animate

Comment: That causes it to delay another 10s after the button has already transitioned

Comment: @LeandroLima After playing around a bit more, this has gotten me a bit closer to where I want, I guess in the end I was hoping more for a solution that would wait specifically for the end rather than having to use delays - animate('1.5s 2s', style({transform: 'translateY(0%)'}))